# Hybris: How to create separate log4j log files in the same extension

Tags: log4j, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to log some audit logs to a separate file than standard console logs. I tried to create custom logger with the properties added to custom extension

```
log4j.appender.auditLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.auditLog.File=/somelogsfile.log
log4j.appender.auditLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.auditLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.category.auditLogger=INFO, auditLog
log4j.additivity.auditLogger=false
```

Then i have initialised logger as:

```
Logger LOG2= Logger.getLogger("auditLogger");
LOG2.info("Test");
```

The logs are output to standard console logs but not to the specified File. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated question, I did some extra investigation and tested it out on my own system.

Most likely, your hybris version is making use of `log4j2` this means that the config should be like this:

```
log4j2.appender.auditLog.type=File
log4j2.appender.auditLog.name=auditLog
log4j2.appender.auditLog.fileName=${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/audit.log
log4j2.appender.auditLog.layout.type=PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.auditLog.layout.pattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j2.logger.auditLogger.name=auditLogger
log4j2.logger.auditLogger.level=info
log4j2.logger.auditLogger.appenderRefs=auditLogger
log4j2.logger.auditLogger.appenderRef.auditLogger.ref=auditLog
log4j2.logger.auditLogger.additivity=false
```

I've tested this out on my local system, and using `Logger LOG= Logger.getLogger("auditLogger")` prints the log statements to the new file

Comment: I am initialising Logger as Logger LOG= Logger.getLogger("auditLogger"); LOG.info("Test"); Does it still require configuration for classes?

Comment: You are correct. I've did some extra testing on my own system and updated the anwser based on my findings. With this config, it works on my test system (1811)